# any Digital Rights Managements (DRM) Tools?

Tags: windows, security, drm

Any tools (better free) on Windows which could do Digital Rights Managements (DRM)? What I need is to control that a licensed computer can open a specific document. And if user distribute the document to some non-licensed computers, the document can not be opened.

BTW: besides this feature, any other easy to demo DRM features on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is built into server 2008.  http://www.kreslavsky.com/2008/12/configuring-digital-rights-management-drm-windows-2008.html

http://whitepapers.techrepublic.com.com/abstract.aspx?docid=2319477&tag=content;leftCol is a podcast on the subject - requires free registration

Comment: Cool, I am looking for some downloadable video demos or ppt or pdf files for this technology. Any recommendations?

Comment: no idea on the demo video...i only knew it was possible from sitting the MCITP:Enterprise Admin cert...if you find some CBT on server 2008 it probably has that in the video somewhere

Comment: http://whitepapers.techrepublic.com.com/abstract.aspx?docid=2319477&tag=content;leftCol requires free registration

Comment: Thanks aking1012, I find it only contains voice, any video demo or ppt file?

Comment: not that i could trivially locate

Comment: "not that i could trivially locate"? -- What do you mean? If you mean there is video demo or ppt file downloadable, could you share the Url please? Thanks.

Comment: i get your question...no i don't have a link.  i could probably find some CBT somewhere on the subject, but I wouldn't be able to dump a link to a warez on a community board

Comment: computer based training...think the videos training packages from trainsignal/cbtnuggets/globalknowledge/whoever else